# HiveQL in HIve vs HiveQL in Spark 2.x

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Apache Spark 2.x supports queries in HiveQL. Are there any noticeable differences between the HiveQL dialect in Apache Hive and the HiveQL dialect in Apache Spark, or can I safely move a query from one to the other without rewriting it?

This question is about the HiveQL *language* as implemented in Apache Hive and Apache Spark 2.x. (i.e. not asking about differences between the Hive query engine and the Spark query engine.)